# Copy site address from Chrome to work like in Chromium Edge

Tags: google-chrome, hyperlink

New Chromium based Edge has a great feature: when I copy address of a page it not just pastes the link, but creates a hyperlink with text as site's title and link added as hyperlink.

This is how looks like when I copy superuser.com's address:

[image]

Is there a way to achieve the same also in Chrome?

It's in Windows 10

Comment: All indications point to Microsoft developing this functionality internally. Whether it gets ported back to Chromium and then merged into Chrome remains to be seen. Have you looked for the analogous controls inside Chrome? In a brief search I haven't found any documentation on this. I'm perusing the various Chrome settings oages in chrome://about, but I'm guessing it'll need a plugin to get this function.